# error with vectorized function in Julia: "arrays could not be broadcast to a common size"

Tags: julia

I get an error when trying to evaluate the following function in Julia (Version 0.3.11, 2015-07-27 06:18 UTC, LinuxMint Rebecca):

```
# this_script.jl
# global parameters
c = [ 1.0 , 2.0]
u = [-1.0 , 3.5]

# A simplified version of a more complicated function
function f(x,y)
    xi = c .* (x/y - u)

    1.0 + sum( erfi(xi) )
end

@vectorize_2arg Number f
```

I can evaluate things like `f(2,1)`, `f(2+im,1)`, or

```
x=linspace(-2,2,4);
f(x,x)

y=rand(4,4)
f(y,y)
```

**However, the following lines throw an error:**

```
u=repmat(x,1,4)
f(u,u)

ERROR: arrays could not be broadcast to a common size
 in broadcast_shape at broadcast.jl:40
 in .* at broadcast.jl:278
 in f at operators.jl:377
 in include at ./boot.jl:245
 in include_from_node1 at ./loading.jl:128
while loading this_script.jl, in expression starting on line 103
```

After that, I cannot evaluate `f` anymore even with `f(2,1)` nor `f(x,x)`. Notice that `u` and `y` have the same dimensions and type.

**How can I handle this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you've updated `u` to be 4x4, but `c` is still a two element vector.

```
julia> c,u
([1.0,2.0],
4x4 Array{Float64,2}:
 -2.0       -2.0       -2.0       -2.0
 -0.666667  -0.666667  -0.666667  -0.666667
  0.666667   0.666667   0.666667   0.666667
  2.0        2.0        2.0        2.0     )

julia> c.*(1/2-u)
ERROR: DimensionMismatch("arrays could not be broadcast to a common size")
```

(As an aside, note that globals like `c` and `u` can be a [performance trap](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/manual/performance-tips/#avoid-global-variables) unless they're marked as `const`.)

Comment: oh, I didn't notice that :( I have some problems with declaring `c` or `u` as `const`, since I should update some of their components depending on restrictions of the case study (for example, `u[1] = sum( c[2:end] .* u[2:end]`)

Comment: ups, it seems that `const` prevents to change the type of the variable, but only prints a warning when changing its value ([link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/julia-users/75SQE65vf0w))